# Is there one way to write the permutation that takes $(1,2,...,n) \rightarrow (n,n-1,...,1)$ that is the same whether $n$ is even or odd?

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

Is there one way to write the permutation that takes $(1,2,...,n) \rightarrow (n,n-1,...,1)$ that is the same whether $n$ is even or odd?

Are these formulas correct?

If $n$ is even then this permutation is given by $(1,n)(2,n-1)...(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2}+1)=\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}(k,n-(k+1))$

If $n$ is odd then this permutation is given by $(1,n)(2,n-1)...(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n+2}{2})=\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(k,n+1-k)$

Is there another way of expressing this permutation that is independent of whether $n$ is even or odd?? Perhaps without breaking it down to transpositions, using cycle notation or something? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write it as $\sigma(k)=n-k+1.$

Comment: Where $(1,2,3,...,4)$ sends $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $3$,... etc? There is a lot of different notation floating around when it comes to denoting permutations >.<

Comment: @WingedReptile I'm only aware of one way of writing cycle notation, and yes, the cycle $(1, 2, \ldots, n)$ sends $1 \mapsto 2, 2 \mapsto 3, \ldots, n \mapsto 1$.

Comment: Then the inverse sends $2$ to $1$, not to $n-1$...

Comment: Ah.  I misunderstood the question.